# When using an external diff tool for Git, how can I get the full path to be passed to the tool rather than the relative path?

Tags: macos, git, p4merge

I'm trying to use a shell script and .gitconfig to open up p4merge (on Mac) when diffing files with git.

It's almost working, but I get a problem with the relative path on the "right" file (second file) which is passed to p4merge:

```
~> git diff <absolute path>/django/templates/pagination.html 
output: 
/<absolute path to prev version>//jtpgjm_pagination.html django/templates/pagination.html
Incorrect parameters: 'django/templates/pagination.html' is (or points to) an invalid file.
```

The full path is being expanded on the first parameter, but not on the second. Is there something I can do to trigger the full file path for the second file?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`readlink -f django/templates/pagination.html`

As an argument to command, for example:

`echo $(readlink -f django/templates/pagination.html)`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work on Mac OSX.. I get this error: `readlink: illegal option -- f`

Comment: In that case you can try: `ls $PWD/django/templates/pagination.html`